# How to get absolutely positioned element visible outside parent div

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I'm trying to get tooltips working properly within a scrollable div container. To achieve this I've set the tooltips position to absolute and for its parent element (`.panel-section`) to relative. Problem is with the very first tooltip which should be visible on top of the `.panel-header` but now it's going "under" it and is not visible.

```css
.panel {
        margin: 50px;
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }

      .panel-header {
        height: 2rem;
        background-color: silver;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      }

      .panel-content {
        overflow-y: auto;
        height: 500px;
      }

      .panel-section {
        position: relative;
      }

      h1,
      h2 {
        margin: 0;
      }

      .tooltip {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid silver;
        background-color: #333333ee;
        color: silver;
        position: absolute;
        top: -50px;
        display: none;
      }

      .panel-section:hover .tooltip {
        display: block;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-header">
        <h1>Header content</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-content">
        <div class="panel-section">
          <h2>Blah blah</h2>
          <div class="tooltip">
            tooltip content
          </div>
          <p>
            (hover here to see tooltip) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ut est quis enim eleifend consequat.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer
            tristique fringilla sapien a ornare. Etiam sed nunc orci. Sed
            maximus ullamcorper risus, sed rutrum magna lobortis ut. Praesent
            egestas hendrerit commodo. Donec dapibus bibendum ex id gravida.
            Donec imperdiet pharetra dolor ac lacinia. Quisque lobortis elit eu
            tempus maximus. Nam eget sem eleifend, pretium massa a, efficitur
            nisi. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque imperdiet felis sed nisl
            consequat suscipit. Morbi convallis tortor in iaculis aliquet.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-section">
          <h2>Blah blah</h2>
          <div class="tooltip">
            tooltip content
          </div>
          <p>
            (hover here to see tooltip) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ut est quis enim eleifend consequat.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer
            tristique fringilla sapien a ornare. Etiam sed nunc orci. Sed
            maximus ullamcorper risus, sed rutrum magna lobortis ut. Praesent
            egestas hendrerit commodo. Donec dapibus bibendum ex id gravida.
            Donec imperdiet pharetra dolor ac lacinia. Quisque lobortis elit eu
            tempus maximus. Nam eget sem eleifend, pretium massa a, efficitur
            nisi. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque imperdiet felis sed nisl
            consequat suscipit. Morbi convallis tortor in iaculis aliquet.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-section">
          <h2>Blah blah</h2>
          <div class="tooltip">
            tooltip content
          </div>
          <p>
            (hover here to see tooltip) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ut est quis enim eleifend consequat.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer
            tristique fringilla sapien a ornare. Etiam sed nunc orci. Sed
            maximus ullamcorper risus, sed rutrum magna lobortis ut. Praesent
            egestas hendrerit commodo. Donec dapibus bibendum ex id gravida.
            Donec imperdiet pharetra dolor ac lacinia. Quisque lobortis elit eu
            tempus maximus. Nam eget sem eleifend, pretium massa a, efficitur
            nisi. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque imperdiet felis sed nisl
            consequat suscipit. Morbi convallis tortor in iaculis aliquet.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it a solution for you to show only the first tooltip below the text and others above?

Comment: No. They should all be above.

Comment: Is `margin-top:50px` for the `.panel-section` good enough?

Comment: No. The point is to get them to be "floating" above the content. In the actual application there will be a lot more tooltips, basically on every line of the content.

Comment: Have you tried to use z-index? set `.tooltip {z-index:10;}`

Comment: @ayang726 Have you tried it before suggesting to him? It doesn't make sense to just recommend random properties, it is not helping anyone. I am saying this because z-index doesn't have any impact in the current scenario. 

Back on topic, after some research, I am not sure this is possible to be implemented with position: absolute and even with pure CSS. Javascript for the rescue - put `position: relative` to the element and with Javascript calculate where to position it on hover of the parent.